# How to extract the certain variable from output of coding

Tags: list-manipulation, output, character-encoding

Good day,

Can anyone help me how can I extract the certain value from the output after run the coding.

```
α= Pi; 
Sm1 = m1^2; 
Sm2 = m2^2; 
Sm3 = Sm1 + Sm2; 
Sm4 = Tr[Sm3]; 
Sm5 = 2 - Sm4; 
For[t = 0, t < 20, t++, eg = eg = {{1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] -  (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
{1/4, 1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)* ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
{(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2]  - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2, ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])}, 
{(1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), 
((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])*((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2]), ((1/2)*Cos[(α*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(α*t)/2])^2}}; 
Print[eg];Print[t]; m1 = TraceSystem[eg, {1}]; m2 = TraceSystem[eg, {2}];  conc =   Sqrt[Sm5];Print["m1 adalah:", m1]; Print["m2 adalah:", m2]; Print["Sm1 adalah:", Sm1];Print["Sm2 adalah:", Sm2]; Print["Sm3 adalah:", Sm3]; Print["Sm4 adalah:", Sm4]; Print["Sm5 adalah:", Sm5]; Print["conc adalah:", conc]; t = t + TimeUsed[]; ]
```

From the coding above, I get the output as below;

```
{{1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4},{1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4},{1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4},{1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4}}

t=0

m1 adalah:{{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}

m2 adalah:{{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}

Sm1 adalah:{{1/4,1/4},{1/4,1/4}}

Sm2 adalah:{{1/4,1/4},{1/4,1/4}}

Sm3 adalah:{{1/2,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}

Sm4 adalah:1

Sm5 adalah:1

conc adalah:1

{{1/4,1/4,0.299404,-0.188035},{1/4,1/4,0.299404,-0.188035},  {0.299404,0.299404,0.358572,-0.225194},{-0.188035,-0.188035,-0.225194,0.141428}}

t=7.143

m1 adalah:{{0.608572,0.0248065},{0.0248065,0.391428}}

m2 adalah:{{1/2,0.11137},{0.11137,0.5}}

Sm1 adalah:{{0.37036,0.000615362},{0.000615362,0.153216}}

Sm2 adalah:{{1/4,0.0124032},{0.0124032,0.25}}

Sm3 adalah:{{0.62036,0.0130186},{0.0130186,0.403216}}

Sm4 adalah:1.02358

Sm5 adalah:0.976424

conc adalah:0.988142

{{1/4,1/4,-0.108197,-0.336591},{1/4,1/4,-0.108197,-0.336591}, {-0.108197,-0.108197,0.0468265,0.145673},{-0.336591,-0.336591,0.145673,0.453174}}

t=14.302

m1 adalah:{{0.296826,0.395673},{0.395673,0.703174}}

m2 adalah:{{1/2,-0.444788},{-0.444788,0.5}}

Sm1 adalah:{{0.0881059,0.156557},{0.156557,0.494453}}

Sm2 adalah:{{1/4,0.197836},{0.197836,0.25}}

Sm3 adalah:{{0.338106,0.354393},{0.354393,0.744453}}

Sm4 adalah:1.08256

Sm5 adalah:0.917441

conc adalah:0.957831
```

How can I add the command in the coding input that extract the t and conc and make them in table as below?

```
t     conc
0      1
7.143  0.988142
and so on
```

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear to me that this is actual Mathematica code, what is the long body above supposed to be doing?

Comment: By "output", do you mean the actual output or `Print`ed lines, or...? If it's the former, you can try `%` or its derivatives. Also, I believe modifying your actual code (not the output) would make the task much easier...

Comment: ok.i will edit it. actually I want the output in table as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is working template code for you. 
I am not sure about your question. But you can use following format to get the desired output you want.

Lets make a function of your matrix

```
 eg[t_] := {{1/4, 
      1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), (1/
      2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])}, {1/4, 
      1/4, (1/2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), (1/
     2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])}, {(1/
     2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), (1/
     2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), ((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])^2, ((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])*((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])}, {(1/
   2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), (1/
   2)*((1/2)*Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), ((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] - (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])*((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2]), ((1/2)*
    Cos[(Pi*t)/2] + (1/2)*Sin[(Pi*t)/2])^2}};
```

Initial list

```
    clist = {con};
    tlist = {time};
```

For loop

```
    For[t = 1, t < 20, t++,

       m1 = Tr[eg[t]]*1;
       m2 = Tr[eg[t]]*2;
       Sm1 = m1^2;
      Sm2 = m2^2;
       Sm3 = Sm1 + Sm2;
      Sm4 = Sm3*t;
     Sm5 = 100 - Sm4;
      conc  = Re[Sqrt[Sm5]] // N;
     t = t + TimeUsed[]/60;
     clist = AppendTo[clist, conc];
     tlist = AppendTo[tlist, t];

    ]
```

formatting

```
     Transpose[{tlist, clist}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. really help me

Comment: I want to ask...after TimeUsed, what add /60?

Comment: TimeUsed returns large cpu number in seconds, so I divided by 60. you can remove it. Just to return output. Note. t is less than 20.